# Excel - VBA - formula error 1004 -

Tags: vba, excel

I'm getting an run-time error '1004' application-defined or object-defined error when I'm using the following vba code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim formul as String

'Run Tercih14

formul = "=vlookup($c$15;'Şube Listesi'!$B:$J;9;FALSE)"


Sheet35.Range("F12").Formula = formul

End Sub
```

I can change the value of the `F12 cell.assign` different formulas like `=sum(A1:A2)` etc. If I create a new sheet and edit the code for the new sheet it works fine with the `vlookup` formula.
I checked, the sheet is not protected . I'm having trouble figuring out what the problem is here. Hope you guys can help me find the solution.

Comment: Does typing in manually the above formula in sheet35 cell F12 work without error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
"=vlookup($c$15;'Şube Listesi'!$B:$J;9;FALSE)"
```

to

```
"=vlookup($c$15,'Şube Listesi'!$B:$J,9,FALSE)"
```

You are using ;'s instead of ,'s

Comment: Thank you so much, i thought sheet names wouldn't effect it but it effect as it seems

Comment: The sheet name was not the problem.  Merely the incorrect delimiter used for the Vlookup. @ozgur

Comment: My code had changed Şube to Sube. I have corrected, well spotted ozgur and clarity from worksmarter.

Comment: When i define formul as a string thought it has to be  same as the excel now  I understand that VBA replaces " , " to " ; " :) . Thanks again guys

Comment: It is the same as excel, vba does not replace anything. Your code in the OP had ";" in not "," in

Answer (score 0):

I had the same kind of issue with a formula containing variable

```
        Dim Instruc As String
        Instruc = "=MAX(R" & CStr(suiv) & ";S" & CStr(suiv) & " )"
        MAIN.Cells(suiv, 20).Formula = CStr(Instruc)
```

When I use the **;** caracter in the formula, I always get the run-time error '1004' application-defined or object-defined error 
I used a variant of the formula with the : caracter

```
        Dim Instruc As String
        Instruc = "=MAX(R" & CStr(suiv) & ";S" & CStr(suiv) & " )"
        MAIN.Cells(suiv, 20).Formula = CStr(Instruc)
```